# Trouble referencing object from within function - adobe animate canvas

Tags: javascript, html, createjs, animate-cc

I am having trouble getting a function to reference a movie clip on the stage (`thatsRight`).  I can reference it outside of a function to initially set it `visible = false` and inside the `this.Correct` function to visible = true, but calling another function `this.removeAndCheck` can not reference the same movie clip on the stage.  I get the error

> "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'this.thatsRight.visible = false')"

on the line in the this.removeAndCheck function.  This doesn't make sense to me.  One function can reference the movie clip but another can not.  This code is on frame.

```
this.thatsRight.visible = false;

this.Correct = function() {

  this.thatsRight.visible = true;

  setTimeout(this.removeAndCheck, 3000)
}


this.removeAndCheck = function() {
  this.thatsRight.visible = false;
  this.CheckAllCorrect();
  }
```

I am also have issue with this.CheckAllCorrect() being called.  `this.CheckAllCorrect()` is also on from one but on another action layer.

This is part of a conversion of different as3 flash assets to html5 canvas assets using adobe animate CC.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure how canvas work on Adobe Animate, but I guess you should be passing "this" argument in the settimeout method and then access it there. For example setTimeout(this.removeAndCheck, 3000, this) and then this.removeAndCheck = function( value ). "value" parameter will hold reference to "this"

Comment: FYI this isn't AS3, it's just JS. I'll remove the `[actionscript-3]` tag.

Answer (score 0):

@Sammeer is correct, this is a scoping issue. Typically I get around this with a `Function.bind`

```
setTimeout(this.removeAndCheck.bind(this), 3000);
```

You might also see local variable binding like this:

```
var that = this;
setTimeout(function() { that.removeAndCheck(); }, 3000);
```

Here is some [further reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval#The_this_problem).

Answer (score 0):

This is a scoping issue with the value of the `this` variable, which is a common mistake in javascript. To avoid these issues completely, just use arrow functions instead:

```
this.thatsRight.visible = false;

this.removeAndCheck = () => {
  this.thatsRight.visible = false;
  this.CheckAllCorrect();
}

this.Correct = () => {
  this.thatsRight.visible = true;
  setTimeout(this.removeAndCheck, 3000)
}
```